# Show seachresult only when first typed letter is hit

Tags: angularjs

I'm playing around with AngularJs and having this code below witch is a search function. The thing is it always shows the whole list of names before I'm typing it in. And in my list I'm going to have over 200 names (that is a long list). The thing I'm trying to achieve is to just show the list when I hit the first letter in the textbox. How can I achieve that? // Thanks

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
                <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John'},
                       {name:'Mary'},
                       {name:'Mike'},
                       {name:'Adam'},
                       {name:'Julie'},
                       {name:'Juliette'}]"></div>
                <span style="color: white">Search:</span> <input ng-model="searchText">
                <table style="color: white" id="searchTextResults">
                    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
                        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>


<script>
            var expectFriendNames = function (expectedNames, key) {
                element.all(by.repeater(key + ' in friends').column(key + '.name')).then(function (arr) {
                    arr.forEach(function (wd, i) {
                        expect(wd.getText()).toMatch(expectedNames[i]);
                    });
                });
            };

            it('should search across all fields when filtering with a string', function () {
                var searchText = element(by.model('searchText'));
                searchText.clear();
                searchText.sendKeys('m');


                searchText.clear();
                searchText.sendKeys('2');

            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only display the table when the search text is not blank:

```
<table ng-show="searchText.length != 0">
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. But this works this way: When I have not typed anything in the textbox the whole table shows. It's first when i typed something in the texbox and then erase the text that the table becomes empty

Comment: Make sure to initialize searchText to an empty string in your controller. You might also use `!!searchText` instead of `searchText.length != 0`

Comment: I think you better to use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` because `ng-show` still creates hundreds of elements and hide it despite `ng-if` simply not creating any element.

Comment: @allenhwkim it's a trade-off between memory usage and speed of dom update. But you're right, ng-if can be used as well.